# Upload image from mobile app to API with multipart/form-data

Tags: c#, api, web-services, xamarin, dotnet-httpclient

I have this API where I receive an image to save it in a storage server. I've been testing the functionality in postman and works perfectly fine. But when it comes to the mobile app it does not send the image.

[here you can see the Postman POST request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fK1ug.png)

the code for the xamarin app is the next

```
        var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
        var stream = File.OpenRead(_mediaFile.Path);
        var streamcontent = new StreamContent(stream);
        content.Add(streamcontent, "picture");
        var client = new HttpClient();
        HttpResponseMessage response = await cliente.PostAsync($"http://localhost:200/api/.../picture", content);
        string result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result; 
        Response responseData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(result);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Correcto", "Imagen subida Correctamentel!", "OK");
            _mediaFile = null;
            terminado.IsEnabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            terminado.IsEnabled = true;
            await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Error", "Opps algo ocuirrio mal!", "OK"); }
```

As you can see in the postman the key `picture` receives the image name. I tried it also with curl and it works:

```
curl -X POST "http://localhost:200/api/.../picture" -H  "accept: application/json" -H  "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F "picture=@version1.jpeg;type=image/jpeg"
```

Comment: is your request even reaching the server?  Are you getting an HTTP response code or timeout?  Using "localhost" in a mobile client is usually not a good idea.  Try the IP or FQDN of the server instead

Comment: Yes, it gives me this error: StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:

Comment: Also, I'm noticing Postman creates example code for most languages. It ran fine in console but uses RestSharp instead HttpClient. I'm gonna try it anyway

Comment: Did you try adding a filename? `content.Add(streamcontent, "picture", "picture.jpg");`

Comment: Did you solved it?

Comment: I did. But I used RestSharp instead. Btw I didn't gave it a filename 'cause the server gives it a unique name, to keep them stored as unique.

Comment: @AliMaldonado Hi, if have solved that, remember to update the solution in answer when you have time , it will help others who have similar issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed it to work, but using RestSharp library instead of HttpClient:

```
var client = new RestClient("192.168.0.2"); //the ip of your REST API
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST); 
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data"); // I'm using multipart form data
request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLC"); // using JWT for auth
request.AddFile("pictureField", "/path/to/file"); //the path depends on which device you're using
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

Pretty much straigt forward and works perfectly fine. Also, the "pictureField" depends on the name of the field the API requires, and the path to file should not be hardcoded. It should be given depending on where in the device the choosen image is.

Comment: Hi, you could mark the answer when you have time, it will help others who have similar issue to know the solution. :-)

Comment: Sorry, forgot it. Done :)